# How dow I install adobe flash player

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, lxterminal

I have the latest version of the RPI . I have tried `wget http://odroidxu.leeharris.me.uk/PepperFlash-15.0.0.152.r2-armv7h.tar.gz` but that gave me a error which means the website could not be found. Can some one please help me?

Comment: Could you give an output of the error, we have not got a lot to go off here.

Answer (score 4):

There is a free Flash implementation on Linux called `gnash`. You can install it standalone (`apt-get install gnash`), or as a browser plugin (`apt-get install browser-plugin-gnash`).

I tested it in Iceweasel (now Firefox again) some time ago and it worked, but the performance wasn't exactly stellar.

Answer (score 1):

You need a more recent Chromium browser by following [this tutorial](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=63&t=121195). then you need to install Pepper Flash following [this other tutorial](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=66&t=99202).
Adobe Flash itself is not available for the Raspberry Pi.

Answer (score 0):

flash is included by default in chrome/chromium ARM for raspberry in raspbian